# Conversion to firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

what becomes of of the

> TStatusBar.Simpletext

property while converting a program from VCL to firmonkey ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `TLabel` on top of the `TStatusBar`, set the `Align` property to alClient. Set the label text property, and there you are.

Fmx components tries to reuse as much as possible from other basic components.
Unfortunately, the help documentation is not very informative.

Study the [FMX.ControlsDemo_Sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/FMX.ControlsDemo_Sample).